# Trouble reading documents within links

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pdfminer

I can't seem to figure out how to read the text inside this link which is a pdf document. I do not get any errors nor do I get back any type of text.

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
import PyPDF2

def read_pdf_from_url(url):
    try:
        response = urlopen(url)
        pdf_file = BytesIO(response.read())
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
        text = ""
        for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
            page = reader.pages[page_num]
            text += page.extract_text()
        return text
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

url = 'https://probaterecords.shelbyal.com/shelby/search.do?indexName=shelbyimages&lq=Instrument%3A19890308000066440&page=1&view=FitV&scrollbar=0&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&messages=0?iframe=true&width=50%25&height=95%25'
text = read_pdf_from_url(url)
print(text)
```

Comment: What do you mean the link does not work? It you paste it in browser it pulled up a document. I' am trying to get python to read the text within that document without actually downloading and saving it on my computer. I thought that was the purpose of BytesIO. But when I run the query I get nothing back for the text. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I see. Here is the link to the website. You can enter any name and look at any document.I just need to figure out how to read one of them. I been all over forums and can't seem to find a solution. https://probaterecords.shelbyal.com/shelby/search.do?indexName=opr

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Ill do some more research on your suggestions.